# Capturing syscall stdout without writing to file in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, system-calls

I want to read the std output of a system call into a C/C++ string. Can I do this without using a temp file?

Perl

```
//without file io
$output = `echo hello`;
```

C++

```
//with file io
system ("echo hello > tmp");
std::fstream file ("tmp");
std::string s;
file >> s;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646868/how-can-i-capture-another-processs-output-using-c

Comment: The problem here of course is that "system call" is not the same as a "system() call".

Comment: @alex vasi: thanks for the link, I did a search but did not find that page before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using C's [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) (probably the simplest solution, even if it doesn't use C++'s `iostream`):

```
FILE *p = popen("echo hello", "r");
std::string s;
for (size_t count; (count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), p));)
    s += string(buf, buf + count);
pclose(p);
```

Assuming your `iostream` has the non-standard *x*`fstream::`*x*`fstream(int fd)` constructor:

```
FILE *p = popen("echo hello", "r");
std::ifstream p2(fileno(p));
std::string s;
p2 >> s;
p2.close();
pclose(p);
```

Using [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/), you don't have to depend upon non-standard extensions to `iostream`:

```
boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source p2(fileno(p));
```

Unfortunately, Windows is horrible and [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) only works for console applications; for a graphical app:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec;
sec.nLength = sizeof(sec);
sec.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sec.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
HANDLE *h[2];
CreatePipe(&h[0], &h[1], &sec, 0);
SetHandleInformation(h[0], HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)
STARTUPINFO si;
memset((void *)&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.hStdInput = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
si.hStdOutput = h[1];
si.hStdError = INVALUD_HANDLE_VALUE;
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd /c \"echo hello\"", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, NULL);
boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source p(h[0]);
```

(completely untested)

Comment: Wait... you call p2.close() and then pclose() on the same stream. That means you're trying to close it twice. It seems to me that once you passed it to the ifstream you lose control over that stream and you cannot use p any longer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664/windows-c-how-can-i-redirect-stderr-for-calls-to-fprintf) might help you redirect stdout from a system call.