# Can I globally redirect the output of system() calls?

Tags: c++, c, unix, redirect, system

I have a program that executes various shell commands via `system()` and occasionally prints to `cout`. I want to redirect all output coming from `system()` calls to a log file so they don't clutter up the normal output. Can I do this without having to append `> log` to all my system commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can use [popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103047/capturing-syscall-stdout-without-writing-to-file-in-c-c)

Comment: Yeah using popen for reading will hand you a pipe from which you can read the commands stdout and do with it what you want.

Comment: This is only valid for platforms that support `popen`.  FYI, the standard C and C++ specifications do not require platforms to support `popen`.

Answer (score 2):

Close the stdio file descriptors (0, 1, and 2) and re-open them on whatever output device you like.

Answer (score 2):

Using `system` is just a bad idea, period. If you use `fork` and `execve` or `posix_spawn`, you can easily make the necessary redirections and avoid all sorts of vulnerabilities from shell quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a library that wrap process call. It is hard to code from posix. I use [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/), it works fine. you can simply tell the lib how you want the output to be redirected...

my2c