# Do a popen(), put the FILE* pointer in an fstream, what about the pclose()?

Tags: c++, pipe, popen, fclose, pclose

So... I start another process that accepts some input from my program (it could go the other way around too). Something of the sort:

```
FILE *f(popen("sendmail", "w"));
```

Now, I can put f in an fstream so that way I can just use the stream (since my program is in C++, it seems to be a sensible thing to do.)

```
std::ofstream output(fileno(f));
...
output << "To: santa.claus@example.com" << std::endl;
...
```

Up to here, I'm good. Now comes the point where I'm done sending data to the child process. All I want is to close the pipe. From what I know, we are expected to use pclose() because that function ensures that the other process receives all the data. In otherwise words, the pclose() function knows how to cleanly severe a pipe.

Unfortunately, since I put f in an ofstream, I cannot just close it, can I?

```
pclose(f); // proper way to close a pipe
...
ofstream::~ofstream() { ... close(fd); ... } // not the right way to close a pipe
```

Is there a way to capture the close from the ofstream and ensure it closes the way I want it to eb closed.

Comment: I believe this could help you in some way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1105009/2428958

Also, you might want to consider deriving streambuf and implementing your own stream class instead of using std::ofstream in this case - since you cannot attach a custom "close" to the destructor.

Comment: The same code that opened the pipe should close it. I'd suggest associating the pipe with a class whose destructor closes the pipe. You don't need to capture the close -- you can do the close when the object is destroyed.

Comment: @MateuszKołodziejski, That's the perfect answer, may you want to write an actual answer? (although the link did not really help, but deriving from streambuf is what I need to do.)

Answer (score 1):

I would inherit a custom class from ofstream:

```
class PipeStream : public std::ofstream
```

and overwrite destructor

```
PipeStream::~PipeStream { pclose(f) };
```

so that pclose(f) is run before fclose(f)?

Comment: That could be a problem if you want to catch the close() call and it's not virtual, right? Since std::ofstream is a template, I'm not 100% sure how that works, but I would think that's the same as usual classes so someone using just an ofstream could call the wrong close() function...