# Disable Console Output from External Program (C++)

Tags: c++, console, output

My code (a simple console application) calls an external program (also a console application). This program spits out many things to the console, which significantly increases runtime when running in batch mode with 10,000+ iterations.

I've tried several ways to disable the output:

1. Redirecting cout and cerr to fout
   -> obviously works on disabling couts in the current/local program, but doesn't disable anything from an external .exe.
2. Some sources have suggested system("cls"), but all that does is clear the screen after the text has been displayed. This adds even more time.
3. Another suggestion was to hide the console window, but the program still writes to the hidden console, so the entire process still takes more or less the same time.

It seems the only way left is to dig inside the external program's source code and disable all the write commands or redirect it to dev/null or something.

Is there a way to disable a program's write to console commands without having to alter the source code and recompile?

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you actually call that program? If it's `system()`, you should simply redirect the output in the command you put there.

Comment: I was using ShellExecute. How would I redirect the output from system()? I'm not so familiar with that. Googling!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've found possible solutions with system() > and popen. I'll update if I manage to solve my problem.

Comment: @crabwalk: It's OK to answer your own question, if you come up with a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system( "theExternalProgram >nul 2>nul" );
```

Comment: This looks promising, and has the added benefit of not producing a file. May I ask what the "2>nul" part does?

Comment: @crabwalk `2>nul` redirects the standard error stream.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! This solution works well.

Comment: This link was also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103047/capturing-syscall-stdout-without-writing-to-file-in-c-c